# Spring4 +Spring Security-Forcefully expire Session expiry after 'x'sec and refesh of url

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I am having a spring boot web application and login is handled using Spring security. The application is deployed on tomcat server. I want the login session to expire if idle for 30 seconds. Also the requirement is that, if someone refresh the web page , he should be forced to login again.
But i am with more trouble.

The login session is alive even after restarting the tomcat server. The application is not forcing me to re-login, but directly taking me to the page.

I have the below code in my muti-https security class for handling the flow from the UI application part.

```
@Configuration
  @Order(7)
  public static class UIConfigurerAdapter extends
      WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustUserDetails userDetailsService;

    private PasswordEncoder encoder = new CustomEncoder();

    @Override
    protected void configure(
        final HttpSecurity http)
        throws Exception {

      http.csrf()
      .disable().authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
          .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/home")
          .permitAll().and().logout().permitAll()
          .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout").permitAll().and()
          .httpBasic().and()
          .exceptionHandling()
          .accessDeniedPage("/error").and().sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1);

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(
        final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
      auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    /**
     * authenticationProvider.
     * @return AuthenticationProvider
     */
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
      LOG.debug("** set authenticationProvider **");
      final DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
      authenticationProvider
          .setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
      authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
      return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(
        final WebSecurity security) {
      security.ignoring().antMatchers("/static/**", "/webjars/**", "/info", "/health");
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean()
        throws Exception {
      return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher> httpSessionEventPublisher() {
        return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<HttpSessionEventPublisher>(new HttpSessionEventPublisher());
    }

  }
```

How is the configuration to invalidate the session after a time peroid using spring4 and spring security. I do not have a web.xml file. Also how can i force the http session not to be re-used when the user forcefully refreshed the browser.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#common-application-properties)... Search for `server.session.timeout`...